# Grouping JSON output according to specific mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have a mysql table (**name:"messages"**) that has three columns as below:

**messageID, fromUserID, content**

I wish to have a json output using php script like following format; I need to seprate messages of each user (**fromUserID** column).

**JSONOutput:**

```
{
"newCount":"x",
"messages":
[
    {
        "fromUserID":"x",
        "messagesArray":
        [
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"}                
        ]
    },
    {
        "fromUserID":"y",
        "messagesArray":
        [
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"}                
        ]
    },
    {
        "fromUserID":"z",
        "messagesArray":
        [
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"},
            {"messageID":"x","content":"xxx"}                
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**My PHP Script:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY fromUserID");

$outputArray = array();

$outputArray['hasNew'] = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$messagesArray = array();

if($query)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $MSGArray = array();
        $messagesArray['fromUserID'] = $row['fromUserID'];
        $MSGArray['messageID'] = $row['messageID'];
        $MSGArray['content'] = $row['content'];
        $messagesArray['MessagesArray'][] = $MSGArray;      
    }
    $outputArray['Messages'][] = $messagesArray;
}

echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

But with above script I give a wrong result as below:

```
{
"hasNew":6,
"Messages":
[
 {
  "fromUserID":"24",
  "MessagesArray":
  [
   {"messageID":"4","content":"test"},
   {"messageID":"3","content":"test"}, 
   {"messageID":"6","content":"test"},
   {"messageID":"5","content":"test"},
   {"messageID":"1","content":"test"},
   {"messageID":"2","content":"test"}
  ]
 }
]
}
```

My PHP Script just using last **fromUserID** value to grouping messages !!!

Please let me know where I'm wrong ...

Comment: That structure is bad for this sort of thing. You're storing things that should be keys as values, meaning you'll have to search the entire main array to find where you need to be inserting new data.

Comment: @MarcB, Could you please suggest me a good way ?!

Comment: Try replacing $messagesArray['fromUserID'] = $row['fromUserID']; by $messagesArray['fromUserID'][$row['fromUserID']] = array(), then inserting the msg from fromUserID in it.

Comment: @Armage, Tanks for your hint; It works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
if($query)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $MSGArray = array();
        $messagesArray[$row['fromUserID']]['fromUserID'] = $row['fromUserID'];
        $MSGArray['messageID'] = $row['messageID'];
        $MSGArray['content'] = $row['content'];
        $messagesArray[$row['fromUserID']]['MessagesArray'][] = $MSGArray;      
    }
foreach($messagesArray as $value) {
    $outputArray['Messages'][] =  $value;
}
}
```